# Finding the resultant force on this diagram

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, physics

[image]

I'm trying to find the resultant force on this diagram. However, there's nothing I can see. Also believe that this problem can be done with mathematical calculations.

Regards,

Comment: Hint trigonometry.

Comment: @Karl I can get it if you be more clear, sir.

Comment: $12\sqrt{2}\times \cos 45$

Comment: @Karl That's $12$.

Comment: @Karl Am I wrong?;

Comment: Find the components of the force in perpendicular directions in a likewise fashion.

Comment: @Karl yes but am still not getting what you mean clearly. $12\sqrt{2}\times \cos 45 = 12$ and?

Comment: Can anyone take a look?

Comment: Perhaps it is better to review resolving forces? Do you understand vector addition?  The clues I've given so far should be enough, if they are not perhaps review your material or speak to the teacher.

Comment: Do you know ow how to add the two perpendicular vectors (ignoring the diagonal one for now)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read the small picture correctly (all measured in $N$):

- $\vec{F}_1 = \left( \begin{matrix} 4 \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right)$, $\vec{F}_2 = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 6 \end{matrix} \right)$, $\vec{F}_3 = \left( \begin{matrix} -12 \\ -12 \end{matrix} \right)$
- resulting force: $\vec{F}_r = \vec{F}_1 + \vec{F}_2 + \vec{F}_3 = \left( \begin{matrix} -8 \\ -6 \end{matrix} \right)$
- magnitude of resulting force: $|\vec{F}_r|= 10$

Answer (score 0):

In these types of problems you need to choose a set of perpendicular axes, call them $x$ and $y$. They do not necessarily have to be horizontal and vertical. You can decompose any vector into components along $x$ and along $y$, by looking at the angle between a vector and these axes. Do that for every vector. Once you have done that, along each axis you can simply add or subtract real numbers, and you get a resultant component along each axis, call them $R_x$ and $R_y$. The final step is to use Pythagoras' theorem to say $R=\sqrt{R_x^2+R_y^2}$.

In your case, you can choose the axes to be horizontal and vertical. 
Along the horizontal direction, you have $R_x=+4-12\sqrt{2}\cos 45^\circ$. Write the similar expression for $R_y$, then use the formula that I gave you to calculate $R$

Comment: This gives the magnitude of the force. Its direction is still to be found.

Comment: How would you describe the direction? I would say an angle. In a right angle triangle, the angle between the hypotenuse and the adjacent side is given by a trigonometric function. You can use tangent. $\tan\theta=\frac{R_y}{R_x}$

Comment: Yes that's what I think too.  I think the OP would benefit from revisiting writing vectors in component form.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know complex numbers and how they are presented on the complex plane.

Here, the angle(*argument*) of a horizontal arrow pointing to the right is $0$.

Then, the arrow pointing upright has an angle of $\frac{\pi }{2}$.

The arrow pointing to bottom left has an angle of $\pi +\frac{\pi}{4}$.

An arrow of length(*magnitude*) $L$ and angle $\theta$ can be represented by $$Le^{i\theta}$$, where $e$ is the natural e and $i$ is the square root of -1.

The net force equals: $$4e^{0i}+6e^{\pi i/2}+12\sqrt{2}e^{i(\pi +\frac{\pi}{4})}$$.

By using the identity $$e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$$, I think you are able to obtain an answer in form of $a+bi$.

Its magnitude is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$; its angle is $atan2(b,a)$.

Note that $atan2$ is not an ordinary function. Its definition could be found here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: That's a lot to assume, I would assume a lower non-calculus based physics course as seen from a non-major perspective.